# Docker compose : Shared static volume between react app and nginx

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm serving a react app via nginx with docker. My docker-compose config is the following :

```
version: '3'
services:

  app:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/example/www:production
    volumes:
      - app:/var/www/app

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - app
    volumes:
      - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
      - app:/var/www/app
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"

  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./certbot/renew.sh:/usr/local/bin/renew.sh
      - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    entrypoint: /bin/sh /usr/local/bin/renew.sh

volumes:
  app:
```

And the Dockerfile for registry.gitlab.com/example/www:production is the following :

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /app

# build
COPY package*.json ./
COPY src ./src
COPY public ./public
COPY .env* ./

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

# remove build material
RUN rm -f package.json
RUN rm -f package-lock.json
RUN rm -rf src
RUN rm -rf public
RUN rm -f .env
RUN rm -f .env.local
RUN mv build/* .
RUN rm -rf build

CMD rm -rf /var/www/app/*; cp -r * /var/www/app/
```

Instead of what I can see everywhere I don't want my container to run any deamon or proxy to "serve" my react app. It's only purpose is to build and clean the app.

As you can see I'm trying to share a volume between this container and my nginx instance. It's working but it's not updating when the image is. I guess when my image is running it sync with the local volume and gets overwritten by the old version of my app.

I tried to add a CMD to my image to copy at "runtime" all files to mounted volume but it doesn't make any difference.

What is the best option to achieve this ?

I would prefer not to use nginx again in my image since it would add more complexity and so more compute power.

Thank you for your help :)